# Assert not recognized by XUnit

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I want to move from MSTest to XUnit and installed the following VS extentions

[image]

I can write facts and run my tests successfully, but for some reason `Assert` is unrecognised

[image]

Comment: Have you actually added xunit to your project from NuGet?

Comment: Yes xunit 2.0.0 is installed

Comment: Yes version 2.1.0 is installed

Comment: And for the last get-the-simple-stuff-out-of-the-way question, you have `using Xunit;` in the file?

Comment: The VS extension is deprecated, see https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#run-tests-visualstudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed all the advice that was given in the comments and answers provided and made sure that the following was done

- The xunit nuget package is installed
- The xunit.runner.visualstudio is installed
- The using statement for the xunit library is added

I noticed that the nuget packages was not on the latest version available, so I updated to the latest available versions which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any XUnit extensions installed. Instead I installed these packages from NuGet into my Test library.

- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio

Giving:

[image]

And a packages.config of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Then I created a class:

```
using Xunit;

public class FunFacts
{
    [Fact]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(4, Add(2, 2));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FailingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, Add(2, 2));
    }

    int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

The tests then passed and failed as expected.

Steps taken from the [XUnit - Getting Started Page](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html).